# is there any function to make touchable url while converting html text to plain text

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert HTML text into plain text but the URL present in HTML in not touchable in plain text

```
var htmlString = """
<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">The Ministry of Corporate Affairs (MCA) has informed vide Flash Alert that Form AGILE is likely to be revised on MCA21 Company Forms Download page with effect from May 31, 2019.&nbsp;</p>\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">Form AGILE is an application for Goods and services tax Identification number, employees state Insurance corporation registration plus Employees provident fund organisation registration. &nbsp;</p>\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">Stakeholders are advised to check the latest version before filing.</p>\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><a href=\"http://www.mca.gov.in/ /
"""
let encodedData = htmlString.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: false)


var attributedString: NSAttributedString?

do {
    attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData!, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding:NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)], documentAttributes: nil)

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
print(encodedData!)
print(attributedString)
```

Comment: "URL present in HTML in not touchable in plain text" Define "plain text". Are you using a `UILabel`? `UITextView`? How are you setting the `attributedString` to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you convert HTML

```
var htmlString = """
<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">The Ministry of Corporate Affairs (MCA) has informed vide Flash Alert that Form AGILE is likely to be revised on MCA21 Company Forms Download page with effect from May 31, 2019.&nbsp;</p><p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><a href=\"http://example.org\">Link</a></p>
"""

let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: Data(htmlString.utf8), options: [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
], documentAttributes: nil)
textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

That yields:

[image]

Comment: link is not navigating to web page

Comment: If you set `textView.isEditable = false` the link will open on tapping

Answer (score 0):

You can just go through `UITextView` for simple plain text with touchable.

Set `UITextView` property `Link` and `Selectable` is `true`, See the following.

Assign simple plain text to `UITextView`.

[image]

[image]

```
let htmlString = """
The Ministry of Corporate Affairs (MCA) has informed vide Flash Alert that Form AGILE is likely to be revised on MCA21 Company Forms Download page with effect from May 31, 2019.

Form AGILE is an application for Goods and services tax Identification number, employees state Insurance corporation registration plus Employees provident fund organisation registration.

Stakeholders are advised to check the latest version before filing.

http://www.mca.gov.in
"""
        txtView.text = htmlString
```